# hide all elements before specific element

Tags: javascript

with jQuery and having a wrapper container around the contents within each h1, I could easily hide them.

but with no wrapper container, how would one do it?

what's the best way to do something that just hides everything before the next h1?

I'm not using jQuery because this is part of a React app.

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}

span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>h1 <span>x</span></h1>
<p>test 1</p>
<h2>h2</h2>
<p>test 2</p>

<h1>h1-1 <span>x</span></h1>
<p>test 3</p>
<h2>h2-2</h2>
<p>test 4</p>
```

or wrap everything after and before the next h1 in a div tag?

Comment: If the number of subentries is very limited you could always just use the `+` operator: add some class (e.g. expanded) when it should be expanded and then just spam enough: `h1.expanded+p, h1.expanded+p+p, h1.expanded+p+p+p, ... { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

I am able to do it with this css. Just add the class "start" to the h1 from which you want to start collapsing the elements and the class "upto" to the h1 upto which you want the elements to collapse.

**CSS**

```
.start ~ *:not(h1) {
   display: none;
}

.upto ~ * {
  display: block !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<h1 class='start'>h1 <span>x</span></h1>
 ...
<h1 class ='upto'>h1-1 <span>x</span></h1>
```

Here all the elements between start and upto will be hidden. You can have the collapse effect by placing adding the 'start' and 'upto' classes accordingly

The addition of the class to the next h1 could be also done via Javascript. So, I can have a simple js function which sets the 'start' and the 'upto'.

```
function collapse(startHeaderNumber, uptoHeaderNumber) {
    var allHeaders = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    var totalNoOfHeaders = allHeaders.length;

   if (startHeaderNumber > totalNoOfHeaders) {
       return;
   }

   var startHeader = allHeaders[startHeaderNumber - 1];
   startHeader.classList.add('start');

   if (uptoHeaderNumber <= totalNoOfHeaders) {
      var uptoHeader = allHeaders[uptoHeaderNumber - 1];
      uptoHeader.classList.add('upto');
   }

}
```

And you can simply call it like

```
collapse(1 ,2)
```

And it would collapse all the items between headers 1 and 2. Or, you can call it like,

```
collapse(1)
```

which will collapse all elements from the first header till the last.

For a full demo, please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sayanb/Lr2n0ayx/5/)

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you want something similar to jQuery's [`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) function. [Here is a good guide to doing that in vanilla js](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-all-sibling-elements-until-a-match-is-found-with-vanilla-javascript/). The code ends up looking like this:

```
var nextUntil = function (elem, selector, filter) {

    // Setup siblings array
    var siblings = [];

    // Get the next sibling element
    elem = elem.nextElementSibling;

    // As long as a sibling exists
    while (elem) {

        // If we've reached our match, bail
        if (elem.matches(selector)) break;

        // If filtering by a selector, check if the sibling matches
        if (filter && !elem.matches(filter)) {
            elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
            continue;
        }

        // Otherwise, push it to the siblings array
        siblings.push(elem);

        // Get the next sibling element
        elem = elem.nextElementSibling;

    }

    return siblings;

};
```

I obviously don't know the context behind what you are doing, but I reckon there's a better way around it by altering the HTML. This could potentially even let you do some of this with just [css nth child selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: thanks! it's a table of contents component. on mobile we want the users to be able to collapse each section and the wysiwyg doesn't create a wrapper container nor do we want to add it on the backend

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**previousElementSibling**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) recursively to get all of the  siblings of your `h1` elements. Here is working example using `previousElementSibling` :

```js
const elems = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) hidePrev(elems[i]);

function hidePrev(elem)
{
    var pre = elem.previousElementSibling;
    if (!pre) return;
    pre.style.display = 'none';
    hidePrev(pre);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}

span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>h1 <span>x</span></h1>
<p>test 1</p>
<h2>h2</h2>
<p>test 2</p>

<h1>h1-1 <span>x</span></h1>
<p>test 3</p>
<h2>h2-2</h2>
<p>test 4</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have commented the code. And I hope you understand what is going on here, but if not, just comment below.

```js
function hideUntilNextSiblingWithSameName(elementName) {
  /*
   * @Param {elementName: String} 
   * Hide all elements until the next one with the same name
   */
  var trackH1 = 0,
      element = document.getElementsByTagName(elementName)[0],
      node = element.parentNode.firstChild;

  do {
    // Keep truck of element with the same name.
    if (node.tagName === element.tagName) trackH1 += 1;

    // Stop if catch element with same name
    if (trackH1 == 2) break;

    // Do not hide link, script, style and text node
    if (node.nodeType === 3 || node.tagName === "LINK" || node.tagName === "SCRIPT" || node.tagName === "STYLE") continue;
    // Hide element
    else {
      node.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  } while (node = node.nextSibling)
}

hideUntilNextSiblingWithSameName("h1")
```

```html
<h1>h1 <span>x</span></h1>
<p>test 1</p>
<h2>h2</h2>
<p>test 2</p>

<h1>h1-1 <span>x</span></h1>
<p>test 3</p>
<h2>h2-2</h2>
<p>test 4</p>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<script></script>
<style></style>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxGVNG

---

At the moment, I hide the elements. But if you want to even not display the elements, use **`node.style.display = "none";`** instead of **`node.style.visibility = "hidden";`** in the else clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simpler way like the following. The idea is to find the immediate parent of the nodes, `body` in this case, and find all the immediate children of it.

Then, start removing the elements until we've found the desired element. In this example, I've tried to hide the elements, but you can simply change the code the remove them instead.

Following is a working demo:

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('body > *');
const elemBefore = document.querySelectorAll('h1')[1];

for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  let elem = elems[i];

  if (elem === elemBefore) {
    break;
  }

  elem.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}

span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>h1 <span>x</span></h1>
<p>test 1</p>
<h2>h2</h2>
<p>test 2</p>

<h1>h1-1 <span>x</span></h1>
<p>test 3</p>
<h2>h2-2</h2>
<p>test 4</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a trick and hide the

behind the h1 and h2 via css:

```js
const selector = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2');
const clickH = function (event) {
   const h = event.target;
   const attr = h.getAttribute('class');
   if (attr === '') {
      h.setAttribute('class', 'closed')
      return undefined;
   }
   h.setAttribute('class', '')
}
selector.forEach((h) => {
    h.setAttribute('class', 'closed')
    h.addEventListener('click', clickH);
})
```

```css
h1, h2 {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.closed {
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

p {
  height: 30px;
  
}

span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>h1 <span>x</span></h1>
<p>test 1</p>
<h2>h2</h2>
<p>test 2</p>

<h1>h1-1 <span>x</span></h1>
<p>test 3</p>
<h2>h2-2</h2>
<p>test 4</p>
```